# MS.Internal.Xml.Xpath.XpathSelectionIterator instead of value of text node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, evaluate

Why Am I getting 
MS.Internal.Xml.Xpath.XpathSelectionIterator
instead of the value of a text node
on this line of code

```
Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(temparray(0).ToString, encoding)
Dim x As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(reader)
reader.Close() '?
Dim nav As XPathNavigator
nav = x.CreateNavigator()
nav.Evaluate("//*[name()='mcd-Lol'][*[name()='mcd-Number' and text()='1'] and *[name()='mcd-Tamanho' and text()='2']]//*[name()='mcd-Den']/text()")
```

whereas in this online tester
http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester
it works pwefectly?

The Xml only has text nodes and all with namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"   xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
     xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
xmlns:mcd="urn:acss:ccf:facturacaoelectronica:schema:xsd:Normalizados">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
<ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:ExtensionVersionID>NormalizadosExtension:1.0</ext:ExtensionVersionID>
<ext:ExtensionContent>
<mcd:NormalizadosExtension>
<mcd:TotalCare>134.49</mcd:TotalCare>
-<mcd:Lol>
<mcd:Number>1</mcd:Number>
<mcd:Tamanho>2</mcd:Tamanho>
<mcd:Area>Z</mcd:Area>
<mcd:TotalCare>124.94</mcd:TotalCare>
-<mcd:Qual>
<mcd:Area>Z</mcd:Area>
<mcd:NumeroQual>1040192667866500</mcd:NumeroQual>
<mcd:Data>2011-11-29</mcd:Data>
-<mcd:Care>
<mcd:NumeroLinha>1</mcd:NumeroLinha>
<mcd:Den>facial</mcd:Den>
<mcd:Quant>1</mcd:Quant>
</mcd:Care>
...
</mcd:Qual>
...
</mcd:Lol>
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you include a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). This one is not self-contained or correct because your XML input is not well-formed. So we're not even able to try Xpath-Tester to see what you saw there.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably Xpath-Tester gave you a string as a result, which you saw as "working perfectly" because that's what you wanted. But Xpath-Tester wasn't using [`XPathNavigator.Evaluate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8(v=vs.110).aspx). The latter, according to the documentation, returns "result of the expression (Boolean, number, string, or node set)." The XPath expression you passed in selects a set of text nodes (because it's `blah/blah/blah/text()`). So, in accordance with the documentation, Evaluate() returns a node set; and the documentation say "This maps to Boolean, Double, String, or XPathNodeIterator objects respectively." So you get an XPathNodeIterator result, to iterate over your text node set.

If you just want the string value of the (first) text node, you could wrap `string()` around your XPath expression:

```
nav.Evaluate("string(//*[name()='mcd-Lol'][*[name()='mcd-Number' and text()='1']
              and *[name()='mcd-Tamanho' and text()='2']]//*[name()='mcd-Den']/text())")
```

I'm not going to ask why you're using `name()='mcd-Lol'`, with a hyphen instead of a colon, instead of using `local-name()='Lol'` and possibly namespace mappings. You didn't ask about it, so I guess you've got that part working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml linq

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Dim invoice As XElement = CType(doc.FirstNode, XElement)
        Dim mcdNs = invoice.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("mcd")

        Dim results As XElement  = invoice.Descendants(mcdNs + "Lol") _
                      .Where(Function(x) (CType(x.Element(mcdNs + "Number"), Integer) = 1) And _
                                         (CType(x.Element(mcdNs + "Tamanho"), Integer) = 2)) _
                      .FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub

End Module
```